# How to save an image into photo gallery using j2me

Tags: mobile, java-me, nokia, samsung-mobile

I am making an application for nokia, samsung, lg ets using j2me.
I want to save an image into photo gallery of mobile. But i didn't have any idea what path i use to save image?

Answer (score 0):

`String initDir = System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.photos");`

Mobile's Internal Memory can make issue if it is limited. So You should use Memory card to save the images.

You can create a folder in Memory card and access it using `E:/<folder-name>` in to your J2ME code.

Answer (score 0):

Look on this article, [Getting Started with the FileConnection APIs.](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/) Also look on this example, [File Connection Using J2ME api JSR 75.](http://j2mesamples.blogspot.com/2009/02/file-connection-using-j2me-api-jsr-75.html)